# VBA Excel getElementsByClassName without child

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have problem with "getElementsByClassName". I am trying to get only the FIRST one class without any child.

I have:
`Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("typstable")`

But in the results, I got also "typstable tabMundial" what is no needed.
How can I take only the first one result or exactly the name of the class without any child?

Comment: Could you just remove unwanted items from the elements collection?

Comment: Hard to do because there is only tags tr and td without any ID or classes and I don't know exactly quantity of records for the tables what I want. Tables have random records numbers. I can check the data in the excel if the entries is correct and delete the wrong ones but I hope there is a better solution like "html.getElementsByClassName("typstable")[1] or html.getElementsByClassName("typstable")(1)" I don't know. But this solutions also makes the problem if class with child will be first so the best solution will be take only the class tag without any childes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solution for that.

```
 Dim element As IHTMLElement
 Set element = html.getElementsByClassName("typstable")(0)
```

I was trying before:

```
 Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
 Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("typstable")(0)
```

My silly fault with collection.